# Getting error in the windows 2008 r2 server while calling exe file with an argument in the command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-server-2008, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I am calling .exe file with giving a directory. This directory includes three files and my .exe is executing these three files. Everything works perfect in my computer in the command prompt. The command is :
c:\myfolder\myexe.exe "c:\users\administrator\desktop\proj"

'proj' is my folder which includes three files.

But when I use windows 2008R2, this command does not work. Is there a special command for Windows 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run as administrator? right click and "run as admin", give that a shot and let me know

Comment: I solved in a different way. Actually the problem was different than I thought. My exe file was creating a folder according to date-time format of the computer. Unfortunately the date format of windows 2008r2 is like mm\dd\yyyy . Because it includes \ it could not create folder, when I changed the date format of server, everything works perfectly. Thanks :)